# How to select the date in the window phone 7 application?

Tags: c#, silverlight, date, windows-phone-7

I am new to the window phone 7 application development. I am developing an application in which I want to select the date dynamically as we do with calenderextender control in asp.net, datetimepicker control in windows mobile application. In the above cases we simply click on the control & can select the date. I want to how to perform this task in window phone 7 application ? Is there any control in window phone 7 through which we can perform the above task or is there any class through which we can achieve the above purpose. Can you please provide me any code or link through which we can solve the above issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date Picker was released as part of the Windows Phone Toolkit.

Some details offered in these posts.

[Pining for Windows Phone 7 controls? We got ya covered! [Announcing the first release of the Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit!] - Delay's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/09/16/pining-for-windows-phone-7-controls-we-got-ya-covered-announcing-the-first-release-of-the-silverlight-for-windows-phone-toolkit.aspx)

[There are lots of ways to ask for a date [Creating custom DatePicker/TimePicker experiences is easy with the Windows Phone Toolkit] - Delay's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/09/21/there-are-lots-of-ways-to-ask-for-a-date-creating-custom-datepicker-timepicker-experiences-is-easy-with-the-windows-phone-toolkit.aspx)

Comment: Can you please tell me how to retrive the selected date in above case after clicking on button (for e.g. Submit)? I am using SQLite as a database in the backend to store the data. I want to store the selected date into the database. We can identify the value of the selected date in window mobile as 'datetimepicker1.value'. How to identify it in windows phone so that I can store it in database ?